# select max dates from two tables, while joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL, and I'm trying to get how many opened and closed requests does one user currently have.

I have three tables, one for the opened requests, one for the closed requests, and one for the user details.

I've joined the three tables, once with inner join, another time with left outer join.

However I'm facing a problem with making a condition that  outputs data within only the MAX date from the two tables (opened requests, and closed requests).

I've used the code below to join the tables, can you please tell me how to put a condition for getting both max date from the opened requests table "O", and max date from the closed requests table "C"? Shall I use "with clause"? How do I use it here? I want the result to be a table of three columns, the user name, how many opened requests he has, and how many closed requests he has.

```
SELECT COUNT (O.USER_ID) ,COUNT (C.USER_ID), USER_NAME
FROM USER_OREQ O 
  INNER JOIN USER_DETAILS U ON  O.USER_ID = U.ID 
  INNER JOIN USER_CREQ C ON U.ID = C.USER_ID
GROUP BY USER_NAME
ORDER BY USER_NAME ASC
```

Comment: Could you provide example schemas with expected output/result? And as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, an indication of what environment is in use would be helpful as not all databases use the *exact* same syntax accross the board.

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL, and i would like the result to be a table of three columns. The user name, how many opened requests, and  how many closed requests.

Comment: I don't see what the request for the maximum date has to do with the question about how many open and closes a user has.  Sample data and desired results would definitely help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to know how many opened and closed requests does a user have in the most recent date. everyday, some requests are opened and assigned to users.for example, the most recent date is yesterday, i want to know how many opened and closed requests did a user have yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want `GROUP BY` clause with `MAX()` :

```
SELECT USER_NAME, MAX(O.DATE), MAX(C.DATE)
FROM USER_OREQ O INNER JOIN 
     USER_DETAILS U ON  O.USER_ID = U.ID INNER JOIN 
     USER_CREQ C 
     ON U.ID = C.USER_ID
GROUP BY USER_NAME
ORDER BY USER_NAME ASC;
```